# Unable to properly encrypt file upload stream

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt & decrypt a file that was uploaded to a Node.JS server running `express`. The file is uploaded from an HTML form and sent to a function that encrypts the incoming file stream, saving it to a file on the server. To download the file, the encrypted file is retrieved from the server and decrypted, sending it back to the client.

I'm able to properly save the file as plaintext without encryption on the server and download it too without any corruption by directly piping the response to the `readStream` or `writeStream` (see code). However, when I pass in my cryptography functions, the file it outputs becomes partially corrupted.

Corrupted Example:

```
========= input.txt ============
Testing Document!

This is just a testing document!
=================================

========= decrypted.txt =========
@h±²k5øcZxÁ·õ7ÌwBox!

5øcis is just a testing document!
=================================
```

NodeJS Route:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
        const busboyInstance = busboy({ headers: req.headers });
      
        // Create a write stream to save the uploaded file
        let fileName;
        let writeStream;
      
        busboyInstance.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
          fileName = 'encrypted_file.txt'; // Modify the filename as needed
          const filePath = __dirname + '/' + fileName;
          writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      
          // Perform file encryption asynchronously. THIS PARTIALLY CORRUPTS THE FILE
          /*
          aesEncryptFileStream(file, writeStream, 'TESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTE')
            .then(() => {
              file.resume(); // Consume the remaining stream
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Encryption error:', error);
              res.status(500).send('Encryption error');
            });*/

            //For debugging purposes we will just copy the file. THIS WORKS FINE
            file.pipe(writeStream);

        });
      
        busboyInstance.on('finish', () => {
          res.end('Upload complete');
          console.log('File upload complete');
        });
      
        req.pipe(busboyInstance);
      });
      
      // Set up a route for handling file decryption and download
      app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
        try {
          // Create a read stream from the encrypted file
          const fileName = 'encrypted_file.txt'; // Modify the filename as needed
          const filePath = __dirname + '/' + fileName;
          const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
      
          // Perform file decryption asynchronously. THIS PARTIALLY CORRUPTS THE FILE
          //await aesDecryptFile(readStream, res, "TESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTESTE");
      
          //For debugging purposes we will just copy the file. THIS WORKS FINE
            readStream.pipe(res);
            
          console.log('File download complete');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          res.status(500).send('Server error');
        }
      });
```

Cryptography Functions:

```
async function aesEncryptFileStream(inputStream, outputStream, secret) {
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // Initialization vector.

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secret, iv);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        inputStream.pipe(cipher).pipe(outputStream);

        inputStream.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
        });

        inputStream.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

async function aesDecryptFile(inputStream, outputStream, secret) {
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); // Initialization vector.

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Buffer.from(secret), iv);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        inputStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(outputStream);

        inputStream.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
        });

        inputStream.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

I originally thought that this was a header issue, but upon further investigation and trying different header combinations, I'm still seeing partially corrupted data being returned when downloading the file with `/download`. Trying to remove the encryption function and directly piping the file works fine though, so I assume that it is some issue with the encryption/decryption function.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IV needs to be the same when encrypting and decrypting a particular message. You'll need to store the IV alongside the encrypted data and then use that when you decrypt it again.